# Connect Azure Websites (Wordpress) to Storage Account

Tags: wordpress, azure

I am using Azure Websites to host my Wordpress Site.
But my website receive a lot of videos and photos uploaded by users.
My 10GB quota is about to excede.

Asked to Azure support and they said to create a Storage Account but they can't help me how to connect my website to the Storage Account. They told me to ask here... so here I am ;)

Anyone can help me how to connect a Storage Account to a Wordpress website in Azure Websites?

Thanks!

Comment: I am a developer and this issue doesn't really concern strict to a developer.
Since the azure websites it's a recent service, maybe there's a best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this awesome plugin which connects both services:

**Windows Azure Storage for WordPress**
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/windows-azure-storage/

Before install it, make sure to link to the service and get the primary key of the storage.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you should is to:

1. Create azure storage
2. Create a container inside of it
3. Copy access key and storage name

On your site of wordpress:

4. Install a plugin called: Microsoft azure storage
5. Go to your WordPress site, and in settings search for Microsoft azure storage
6. Put your informations that you've copied from azure, like key, and name of storage account.

PS: IF AFTER THAT YOUR CONTAINER IS NOT SHOWING ON WORDPRESS YOU SHOULD FORCE THE AZURE STORAGE BY INJECTING A PART OF CODE INSIDE WORDPRESS FILE CONFIGURATION: *WP-CONFIG.PHP* AND COPY THE CODE BELOW:

```
MICROSOFT_AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME – Account Name
MICROSOFT_AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY – Account Primary Access Key
MICROSOFT_AZURE_CONTAINER – Azure Blob Container
MICROSOFT_AZURE_CNAME – Domain: must start with http(s)://
MICROSOFT_AZURE_USE_FOR_DEFAULT_UPLOAD – boolean (default false)
```